# Waiting for promise in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf.js

I have a bit of trouble getting into this whole async stuff. I'm using pdf.js to read the contents of a pdf file. Everything is working, however the execution order is causing me troubles. This is the code I have:

```
function getText(data) {
    var contents = [];
    PDFJS.getDocument(data).then(function(pdf) {
        var numPages = pdf.pdfInfo.numPages;
        for (var i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
            pdf.getPage(i).then(function(page) {
                page.getTextContent().then(function(content) {
                    contents.concat(content.bidiTexts);
                })
            });
        }
    })
}
```

This is working as intended, however, I would like to pass `contents` when all pages are processed and their bidiTexts are concated to contents. If I just put a function call with `contents` as argument before the last closing `}` then it gets called to early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using promises:

```
function getText(data) {
    var contents = [];
    var promises = [];

    PDFJS.getDocument(data).then(function(pdf) {
        var numPages = pdf.pdfInfo.numPages;

        for (var i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
            var deferred = $.Deferred(); //Create a deferred object
            promises.push(deferred.promise()); //push promise to the list

            pdf.getPage(i).then(function(page) {
                page.getTextContent().then(function(content) {
                    contents.concat(content.bidiTexts);
                    deferred.resolve(); //resolve the deferred object
                })
            });
        }

        $.when.apply($,promises).then(function(){ //callback executed when all deferreds are resolved
            //do your task with contents
        });
    })
}
```

This is just a demo how to use promises. In real applications, you have to take care of errors by using `deferred.reject` and handle it in the second callback to `$.when`

Comment: Thank you, the above was easier, but i'll look into this for additional knowledge

Comment: @Difusio: this is a general solution as you can pass the promises around. You would see its usefulness with other complex cases.

Comment: @Difusio: the above answer has a flaw as it checks for `i === numPages` (actually, this is a trick, not the most recommended way). For example, you have 10 pages, but page 10 returns value before page 9 (in asynch world, this is likely, then your code will miss the page 9). It's likely that you would see this problem sometime.

Comment: Hmmm, do you have a good source to read up on promises? Haven't found anything yet that gives a good explanation.

Comment: @Difusio: I read it in jQuery docs http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ and http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: @Difusio: I don't know whether you need to add contents in order or not. If you need to add to contents in correct page order. This code ensures that all pages are added but may out of order.

Comment: Order is relevant yes, i'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [async/await](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-async-await-in-javascript-1d81bb079b2c)

```
async function getText(data) {
    var contents = [];
    var pdf = await PDFJS.getDocument(data);

    var numPages = pdf.pdfInfo.numPages;

    for (var i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
      var page = await pdf.getPage(i);
      var content = await page.getTextContent();

      contents.concat(content.bidiTexts);      
    }    
}
```

Note that `getText` will return a promise, you can use `async /await` again to access the result or `getText(data).then(result => console.log(result));`

if you want to get the pages in parallel, use `Promise.All` then `await` for the `.getContent()` :

```
async function getText(data) {
  var pdf = await PDFJS.getDocument(data)
  var numPages = pdf.pdfInfo.numPages;

  var promises = [];

  for (var i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
    promises.push(pdf.getPage(i));
  }

  var result = await Promise.All(promises)
    .then(pages => pages.map(page => await page.getTextContent()));

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid using await in a loop, it requires waiting per item, instead collect the promises in an array, and then call `await Promise.all(array)` after the loop, this expecially good if the thing you are waiting for can be paralised