# For loop with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running a for loop which calls a function that does a GET request

```
for (var i = 0; i < uids.length; i++) {

makeRequest(uids[i]);

}

function makeRequest(hostname) {

  request({
    url: url,
    json: true
    }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    //display the data etc
    }
    }

}
```

Is it possible for the for loop to ONLY iterate after each request is made and completed. e.g once the GET request is complete and returns a result?

I thought about implementing some timeouts, however I am not sure that that is the best solution for this.

Comment: You could make a recursive call in your callback and edit the parameters to accept an index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waiting for promise in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813279/waiting-for-promise-in-for-loop)

Comment: I don't see any promises above. Does `request` return one?

Comment: If `request` is using promises its doing it wrong. Your meant to return the promise not wrap it with a callback. If you returned the promise you could do more elegant things like promise chains instead of callback recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Make it recursive until you have items left:

```
var itemsLeft = uids.length;

function makeRequest(hostname) {
   request({
      url: url,
      json: true
   }, function(error, response, body) {
     if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        if( itemsLeft !== 0 ) { 
           makeRequest( hostname );
           itemsLeft -= 1;
        } 
     }
   })
}
```

Comment: This doesn't access any index. You just make the same call

Comment: Ok, but then make it set it in the first query :)

Comment: look at your signature for makeRequest then look at your call to it. You are making the exact same call

Answer (score 0):

Can suggest to take a look into something like https://github.com/FuturesJS/forEachAsync. Check [their example](http://futuresjs.github.io/forEachAsync/) to understand how to use the library.